# How Can I Fix Form Background?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made this form there are several problems with it but I wanted to ask only one of them. When I click number 2-3-4 and 5th boxes their background being blue and I could not fix this problem even tho I tried so hard. I searched from Google and asked many people but they just could not figure it out neither. I want them to look like exactly number 1 form. Also I want to click add another patient and I want to have another form. For example its just form number one and user clicked add another patient I want user to see number 2 form: I shared my codes on code snippet. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks already.

HTML Codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0b27183842.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="navbar">
                <h1 class="heading1">Patient Referral Form Hayes Valley Health San Francisco </h1>              
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h2 class="iki">Referral Patients</h2>
    <h3 class="uc">You can add up to five patients at a time</h3>
    <div class="box">
        <!-- bir başlangıc -->
        <div class="box-header" id="box1">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    1                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral 
                <div class="iconn"  id="iconn" >
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"  ></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;" >
            <div class="form_inp">
             <div class="disflex">    
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
             </div>
              <div class="disflex">    
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="disflex">          
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone"  required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com"  required>
               </div>
              </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
               </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
               </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        <!-- bir bitiş -->
        <!-- iki başlangı. -->
        <div class="box-header" id="box2">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    2                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral 
               
                <div class="iconn"  id="iconn" >
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"  ></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;" >
    
            <div class="form_inp">
             <div class="disflex">    
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
             </div>
              <div class="disflex">    
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="disflex">          
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone"  required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com"  required>
               </div>
              </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
               </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
               </div> 
            </div>   
            </div>
        <!-- iki bitiş -->
        <!--üç başlangıç-->
        <div class="box-header" id="box2">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    3                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral 
                <div class="iconn"  id="iconn" >
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"  ></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;" >
            <div class="form_inp">
             <div class="disflex">    
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
              </div>
             </div>
              <div class="disflex">    
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="disflex">          
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone"  required>
               </div>
               <div class="input-container">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com"  required>
               </div>
              </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
               </div>
               <div class="full-input-container">
                <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
               </div>   
            </div>        
            </div>
        <!--üç bitiş-->
        
        <!--beş başlangıç-->
        <div class="box-header" id="box4">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    5                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral 
                <div class="iconn"  id="iconn" >
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"  ></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="form" style="display: none;" >
<div class="form_inp">
 <div class="disflex">    
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="disflex">    
   <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
   </div>
   <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="disflex">          
   <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone"  required>
   </div>
   <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com"  required>
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="full-input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
   </div>
   <div class="full-input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
   </div>
</div>
</div> 
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <button type="menu" class="patient"> + ADD ANOTHER PATIENT</button>
   <br>
   <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">SEND REFERRALS</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/your-embed-code.js"></script> <!-- TODO: Place your Font Awesome embed code  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Codes:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #CDE7ED;
}
.heading1{
    position: absolute;
width: 449px;
height: 80px;
top: 56px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
#navbar{
position: relative;
height: 196px;
top: 0px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.iki{
height: 32px;
margin-top: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: center;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
.uc{
height: 32px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 32px;
/* identical to box height, or 160% */
text-align: center;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
.box{
    width: 782px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: auto;        
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(11, 43, 91, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.box-header{       
width: 782px;
height: 64px;
left: 249px;
top: 334px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
display: flex;
}
.b1{        
width: 40px;
background: #25A575;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.b11{
height: 100%;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 26px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.new{
padding-left: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
color: #3A719B;
background-color: white;
}
.box-body{
    width: 295px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 24px;
    top: 0px;        
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;      
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;        
    color: #3A719B;
}
.line{
  position: absolute;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
bottom: 0%;
border: 1px solid #3A719B;
}
.disflex {
  display: flex;
}
.form_inp {
  padding: 60px;
}
.disflex .input-container, .full-input-container {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid steelblue;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.disflex .input-container input, .full-input-container input {
  border: 0;
}
.full-input-container {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0 !important;
}
.btn {   
    width: 782px;
    height: 48px;
    left: 249px;
    top: 790px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #0B2B5B;
    border-radius: 34.5px;
}
.patient{
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 800px;   
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;   
    color: #0B2B5B;
    background-color:#CDE7ED ;
    border: none;
}
.iconn{ 
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
text-align: right;
top: 354px;
display: flex;
color: black;
padding-left: 550px;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 16px;
color: #000000;
}
```

JavaScript Codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('asd2')
    $(".box-header").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
        console.log('asd')
      });

     $('#hd_image').hide();
    $("#but_upload").click(function () {

        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#formFile')[0].files;

        // Check file selected or not
         if (files.length > 0) {
             fd.append('file', files[0]);

           $.ajax({
                 url: '',
                type: 'post',
                data: fd,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(response){
                     $('#form_hide').hide();
                     $('#hd_image').show();
                 },
                 success: function (response) {
                     if (response != 0) { 
                         $('#form_hide').show();
                         $('#hd_image').hide();
                        // var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                         console.log(response);
                    } else {
                     alert('file not uploaded');
                         $('#form_hide').show();
                        
                     }
               }
           });
        } else {
            alert("Please select a file.");
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: the form is taking the background color so you can add white background for the form div#form {  background: white;}

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the white background appears in the first forms and not appear as it goes down is that white background color belongs to the **.box** class.

If you just want to make the background of your form white, it is enough to make your **.form_inp** class' background white.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for "*...their background being blue...*" is because the `<div class="box">` have fixed height. So when 2nd, 3rd, and 5th dropdown is expanded, the remaining height of `<div class="form_inp">` doesn't provide enough height inside `<div class="box">`. To solve this, you may take the steps below:

1. **HTML**: Put the buttons below into the `<div class="box">` and remove all near `<br />`

```
<button type="menu" class="patient"> + ADD ANOTHER PATIENT</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn">SEND REFERRALS</button>
```

2. **CSS**: Add `background-color: white;` in `.form_inp`
3. **HTML**: Add `<div class="empty">` under of each `<div class="form_inp">`
4. **CSS**: Add CSS for `.empty` like this

```
.empty {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CDE7ED;
}
```

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('asd2')
    $(".box-header").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200);
        console.log('asd')
      });

     $('#hd_image').hide();
    $("#but_upload").click(function () {

        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#formFile')[0].files;

        // Check file selected or not
         if (files.length > 0) {
             fd.append('file', files[0]);

           $.ajax({
                 url: '',
                type: 'post',
                data: fd,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(response){
                     $('#form_hide').hide();
                     $('#hd_image').show();
                 },
                 success: function (response) {
                     if (response != 0) { 
                         $('#form_hide').show();
                         $('#hd_image').hide();
                        // var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                         console.log(response);
                    } else {
                     alert('file not uploaded');
                         $('#form_hide').show();
                        
                     }
               }
           });
        } else {
            alert("Please select a file.");
        }
   });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #CDE7ED;
}
.heading1{
    position: absolute;
width: 449px;
height: 80px;
top: 56px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
#navbar{
position: relative;
height: 196px;
top: 0px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.iki{
height: 32px;
margin-top: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: center;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
.uc{
height: 32px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 32px;
/* identical to box height, or 160% */
text-align: center;
color: #0B2B5B;
}
.box{
    width: 782px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: auto;        
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(11, 43, 91, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.box-header{       
width: 782px;
height: 64px;
left: 249px;
top: 334px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
display: flex;
}
.b1{        
width: 40px;
background: #25A575;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.b11{
height: 100%;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 26px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.new{
padding-left: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
color: #3A719B;
background-color: white;
}
.box-body{
    width: 295px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 24px;
    top: 0px;        
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;      
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;        
    color: #3A719B;
}
.line{
  position: absolute;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: 100%;
bottom: 0%;
border: 1px solid #3A719B;
}
.disflex {
  display: flex;
}
.form_inp {
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}
.disflex .input-container, .full-input-container {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid steelblue;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.disflex .input-container input, .full-input-container input {
  border: 0;
}
.full-input-container {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0 !important;
}
.btn {   
    width: 782px;
    height: 48px;
    left: 249px;
    top: 790px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #0B2B5B;
    border-radius: 34.5px;
}
.patient{
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 800px;   
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;   
    color: #0B2B5B;
    background-color:#CDE7ED ;
    border: none;
}
.iconn{ 
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  top: 354px;
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 550px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #000000;
}
.empty {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CDE7ED;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0b27183842.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="navbar">
                <h1 class="heading1">Patient Referral Form Hayes Valley Health San Francisco </h1>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h2 class="iki">Referral Patients</h2>
    <h3 class="uc">You can add up to five patients at a time</h3>
    <div class="box">
        <!-- bir başlangıc -->
        <div class="box-header" id="box1">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral
                <div class="iconn" id="iconn">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form_inp">
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- bir bitiş -->
        <!-- iki başlangı. -->
        <div class="box-header" id="box2">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral

                <div class="iconn" id="iconn">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;">

            <div class="form_inp">
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- iki bitiş -->
        <!--üç başlangıç-->
        <div class="box-header" id="box2">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral
                <div class="iconn" id="iconn">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form_inp">
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <!--üç bitiş-->

        <!--beş başlangıç-->
        <div class="box-header" id="box4">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    5
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral
                <div class="iconn" id="iconn">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-square-caret-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form_inp">
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="usrnm" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="email" min="1970-01-01" max="2023-01-01" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-language"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Language" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="disflex">
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-phone-volume"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" pattern=".+@gmail\.com" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Address" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="full-input-container">
                    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Notes/Reason" name="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="menu" class="patient"> + ADD ANOTHER PATIENT</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">SEND REFERRALS</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/your-embed-code.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Place your Font Awesome embed code  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```